# ItemSelectionChanged not invoking command action (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit) - MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I've been searching everywhere and can't get a solution to my issue (not sure if I'm over looking a simple matter). Anyhow, the issue I have is the command action is not being invoked on a CheckListBox (from Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit), please see following:

```
<wpftk:CheckListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" Width="250" Height="175" TabIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAdminManagedDepartments}"
                     SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedDepartments, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="ItemSelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectionCommand}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</wpftk:CheckListBox>
```

However, the following for the combo box would work perfectly when invoking the same command:

```
           <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="29" Width="230" FontSize="14" IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding GetAllAbsenceTypes}"
                      Text="{Binding Path=TYPE_ABSENCE, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TYPE_ABSENCE, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectionCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```

Any help in this matter would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Any help? anyone?